# What's the best way to fix this drywall crack?

Tags: drywall

Note: the crack doesn't go to the top and bottom.
Note: The switch and light are mounted on studs...the crack is in the middle...not on a taped seam.

[image]

Below is the other side.  My theory is that a workman squeezed between the furnace and pushed the stud out slightly.  The wall isn't damaged on the back.  Somehow, just the paper got torn a bit.   Can I sand it smooth and paint it or am I going to have to gouge it out and plaster and tape it?

[image]

Comment: It is not a crack, it is the drywall tape lifting

Comment: @asinine  It's not tape.  It's between the studs...there is no joint there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a quick sanding and paint will fix it. I doubt it. I would just get it over with and cut a vee in it for filling. I half expect that you'll find evidence of a crack running parallel to the sheet's surface in there. If I found that, then I would cut into the wall perpendicular to the vee and deep enough so that I could peel open the newly discovered crack. I'd peel it open just enough to stick some mud in there, tape and mud the vee, and tape and mud the perpendicular cut.

Depending on how big the newly discovered crack was, I might stick a scrap of OSB on the furnace side of the wall and bridge the newly discovered crack with some drywall screws. If those screws are going to stab somebody who services the furnace, then I would remove them after the mud cured/dried.

Comment: Could also just grind the screws flush(ish) with the wood.

Comment: I glued a scrap piece of 1/4" plywood on the back side.   I thought I could use my thumb on sand paper to "dig into" the crack and then plaster over it.   It worked but it took countless iterations.    I should have taken your advice and cut a vee in.  I don't think tape would have been needed since it would leave a bulge and the plaster was already reinforced.